# Declaração do construtor padrão dentro de uma classe em java

Tags: java

Ao criar uma classe no java em IDE eclipse < public class TerceiraQuestao apareceu a declaração public TerceiraQuestao() dentro da classe criada sem que eu a tivesse declarado. Alguem poderia me ajudar? Segue o código..

```
package fundamentos;
```

public class TerceiraQuestao {

```
public TerceiraQuestao() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, sua pergunta não está tão clara. Não quer que seja declarado? Como retirar? Para que serve?

Answer (score -1):

Pessoal queria registrar a solução que foi desmarcar a opção "Constructors from superclass" ao criar a classe .

```
package fundamentos;
```

public class TerceiraQuestao {

}nsira o código aqui

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).